# RxJava combine Single with Completable

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am confused how to use Single with Completable properly.
I have a get method that returns Single and a other method just do saving data and return nothing ( Completable )
Code looks like below :

```
fun getUserInfo() : Single<UserInfo>

fun save(token: Token) : Completable

fun initialize() {
    getUserInfo()
        .flatMap { 
            // Get token from UserInfo : val token = userInfor.getToken()
            // Call save(token: Token) method to save data
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeBy(
            onSuccess = {
                // HERE:  Using UserInfo to do somtehing
            },
            onError = {
                Log.d(it)
            }
        )
}
```

How to write code inside **flatMap** block ? ( Or is there other operator suitable with this use case?)
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMapCompletable`:

```
fun initialize() {
    getUserInfo()
        .flatMapCompletable { userInfo: UserInfo ->
            // save userInfo somewhere. i.e:
            this@MyActivity.userInfo = userInfo
            val token = userInfo.getToken()
            return@flatMapCompletable save(token) 
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeBy(
            onComplete = { // <--------- this becomes onComplete instead of onSuccess
                // Here, you can use userInfo that you saved
            },
            onError = {
                Log.d(it)
            }
        )
}
```

Note that in your `subscribeBy(...)` method, don't forget to change the callback function name from `onSuccess(...)` to `onComplete(...)` since you're transforming single to completable.

Alternatively, if you want to keep `userInfo` as a local variable, you can use `toSingleDefault(...)` to emit it downstream once the completable from your `save(...)` method has finished executing:

```
fun initialize() {
    getUserInfo()
        .flatMap { userInfo: UserInfo -> // change back to flatmap
            val token = userInfo.getToken()
            return@flatMap save(token).toSingleDefault(userInfo) 
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeBy(
            onSuccess = { userInfo: UserInfo ->
                // do something with userInfo ...
            },
            onError = {
                Log.d(it)
            }
        )
}
```

Comment: Yeah. `toSingleDefault ` saved my life ~

Comment: @buzaa Glad to help!